# If you use the bobblehead stand or magazine racks do I assume correctly that they still work for you?

Tags: fallout-4

I am probably unnecessarily concerned, but if you use the bobblehead stand or magazine rack instead of keeping them in your inventory, do you still receive the benefits of the items? It would be counterproductive if that were not the case. I have not seen any thing that states they work the same on the stand/racks as on your character so just  wanted to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Picking up a SPECIAL Bobblehead gives you a stat increase, just as if you'd picked it yourself as a Perk. This happens as soon as you pick it up. There's an added benefit that if you're already at 10 in that SPECIAL, the Bobblehead will push you to 11.

Picking up any other Bobblehead grants a [special perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perks#Bobblehead_perks), but it doesn't show up anywhere you can see it.

Each of the magazines grants a special Perk that show up in the list in your PipBoy. Some stack (e.g. Barbarian), while others do not (like Astoundingly Awesome).

[image: Astoundingly Awesome]

In either case, once you've picked up the magazine or Bobblehead, the actual object is completely useless. Put them on display, dump them in a river, fire them from a Junkjet (maybe?). In any case, the actual object no longer matters.

Comment: Worth a double-checK: I'm pretty sure the Junk Jet only accepts Junk. Though it would be amusing to use it to smack someone in the head with the Melee Bobblehead.

Comment: I think you're correct, but I'm pleased to see you got the picture I was trying to draw. It begs the question, though... When you were imagining shooting somebody in the face with a bobblehead, did you see the victim's head bobbling, too? :)

Comment: @DCShannon No? Screen capture says otherwise.

Comment: @T.J.L. I'm sorry, you can't see *Bobblehead* perks in your Pip-Boy.

Comment: @DCShannon Right you are. I just confirmed, and will update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you continue to have the stats even if you sell the items :)